# Is there a way to rename the save files?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

As I use the save function a lot, to either go back and to things differently, or other various things. I often find the save names incredible hard to distinguish from each other.

Is there a way to rename the save files, or change how the save files are named?

Comment: There's a mod for savefile management. I think it lets you separate out different characters among other things. Maybe I'll try it tonight.

Comment: Hesitating because I haven't tried one yet, and I hear the steam patch might break all of these tools.  However, I'm downloading this one right now. http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=365

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the console, use the `save "<file name>"` command.

You can open the console with the tilde key <kbd>~</kbd>, or the <kbd>²</kbd> key on international keyboards.